# Can I determine amount of oil from engine size, cylinder, and/or displacement

Tags: engine, oil, oil-change

Is there a way to determine how much oil I need to put into my vehicle for an oil change, from any of the size, displacement and/or how many cylinders the engine has?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

No, the capacity of the sump is independant of the cubic capacity of the engine (apart from the general ratio that the larger the cubic capacity then the larger the sump is).

You need to check the owners manual, workshop manual or most oil selling points have reference books with the information ie oil type and amount.

Comment: Don't wing it @KKendall! Too much or too little can lead to engine damage.